# Increment the day value from current day

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

For example, in my case, i already has this value of array.....

```
   array(1) {
   [1]=>
   array(1120) {
    ["2006-02-25"]=>
     array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(33)
    }
    ["2006-02-20"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(38)
    }
    ["2006-02-28"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(46)
    }
```

that result I've got this code

```
    $explodeEndDate = explode(" ",$adEndDate);
    $explodeStartDate = explode(" ", $adStartDate);

    $StartDate = $explodeStartDate[0];

    $NewStartDate = strtotime("$explodeStartDate[0]");
    $NewEndDate = strtotime("$explodeEndDate[0]");

    $timeDiff = abs($NewEndDate - $NewStartDate);

    // 86400 seconds in one day
    $NumberDays = $timeDiff/86400;

    //convert into int
    $NumberDays = intval($NumberDays);


    if(array_key_exists($NumberDays, $array[$itemType]) == false){
        $array[$itemType][$StartDate] =[$NumberDays];
    }
}
```

what I wanted to achieve is, in the `"$StartDate"` value which is for example `["2006-02-28"]` , I wanted to plus it with the value of it. If we referring back to the figure above for example is

```
["2006-02-25"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
       int(33)
```

so `2006-02-25` is the plus by `33` and the result is `2006-04-01`. and after that, i wanted to make the date within that range

Comment: `so 2006-02-25 is plus by 33 and the result is 2006-04-01` while 2006-02-25 is plus by 33  = 20006-03-29. don't you think so?

Comment: Use strtotime function. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($StartDate . ' +' . $NumberDays . ' Days'));` HF

Comment: @Anant no the result should be 2006-03-29 because in 2006 month february has 29 days

Comment: @MuhammadFebrik  what i want to say that what you asked is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add date so here you go:

**Months:**

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+33 months", strtotime('2006-02-25')));
var_dump($date)
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/635914).

**Days:**

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+33 days", strtotime('2006-02-25')));
var_dump($date)
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/635915)

Comment: @MuhammadFebrik where you get this value. Show me your code.